# How to bind event to method on ViewModel with event args passing. Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have seen somewhere this is 100% doable using blend behaviors, cannot find example.

Even better example would be to pass event args and/or sender as CommandParameter to specific command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SizeChanged">
            <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="WndSizeChanged"
                TargetObject="{Binding}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

WndSizeChanged method should be public and have same signature as event delegte it subscribing to.

Answer (score 1):

a comfortable way to create behaviors is to use the DelegateCommand approach as in Prism:

Read here: [Prism behavior](http://development-guides.silverbaylabs.org/Video/Prism-Commands)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, as Delegate Command does not receive the event args.

Comment: you can use generic DelegateCommands with the event args as parameter

Answer (score 1):

[Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions&referringTitle=Documentation) has some nice ways to do this.

From the docs:

```
<Button Content="Remove"
        cal:Message.Attach="Remove($dataContext)" />

$eventArgs – Passes the Trigger’s EventArgs or input parameter to your Action. Note: This will be null for guard methods since the trigger hasn’t actually occurred.
$dataContext – Passes the DataContext of the element that the ActionMessage is attached to. This is very useful in Master/Detail scenarios where the ActionMessage may bubble to a parent VM but needs to carry with it the child instance to be acted upon.
$source – The actual FrameworkElement that triggered the ActionMessage to be sent.
$view - The view (usually a UserControl or Window) that is bound to the ViewModel.
$executionContext - The actions's execution context, which contains all the above information and more. This is useful in advanced scenarios.
$this - The actual ui element to which the action is attached.
```